# SUM `amount` column based on `transactionType` in Postgresql "transactions" table

Tags: postgresql, sum

I have this table:

```
+--------+-----------------+
| amount | transactionType |
+--------+-----------------+
|     10 | Debit           |
|     5  | Credit          |
|    15  | Credit          |
|    20  | Debit           |
|     2  | Credit          |
+--------+-----------------+
```

I can create a `sum` like so: `SELECT sum(amount) from transactions`, however, I need to perform a `sum` based on the column `transactionType` value, ie. `if transactionType === 'Debit', minus the amount, if transactionType === 'Credit', add the amount`

Can postgres do this natively?

Comment: Sure, look up the "case when ...".

Comment: Looks like a simple `GROUP BY`, but this is not a DBA question.